# Xamarin Forms Shell Crashed when navigating too fast between shellContent ( Only for ios )

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, navigation

I am seeing my app crash when navigating between the left menu page of when i click to the back arrow to fast.
the error :"Nav Stack consistency error"
i found this https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8461.
If I slow down and wait a second or so, then I do not get the error.

am using Vs 2019 with new ios version :15, this problem only in ios.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Were you testing on simulator? If so, test on a physical device. Can you get it to happen there?

Comment: ToolmakerSteve i tested on real device

Comment: What model is the phone? And what IOS version?

Comment: iOS version 15.2 , Iphone : Xr

Comment: Can you make a public github repo, with enough code to cause the problem? Strip out any code that isn't relevent.